# Record multi audio tracks available in a stream with MediaRecorder

Tags: mediarecorder, audiotrack, screen-recording, mediastream

I'm building a screen recorder plugin for chrome store. I'm **adding microphone's audio track to the media stream** that contains (**Screen's video track + System audio track**). So final stream contain 2 audio tracks one of microphone and other one of system audio.

When I'm passing this stream to **MediaRecorder(stream)**, than in final video I can able listen only single audio which is at 0 index in **stream.getAudioTracks()**, i.e., MediaRecorder is recording only single audio track.

So how to record a stream containing multi audio tracks using MediaRecorder?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? I'm having the same problem on a videoconference application. I want to save both audio tracks (local and remote) to the same webm file (this file includes the video of the remote end). Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: When multiple audio source is connected, you need to use AudioContext.

Comment: As of the time of writing this, at least Google Chrome only records one track of each kind (audio/video), no matter how many tracks of each kind a stream contains. This is unfortunate in light of how much we depend on video conversation through our private and work life during the pandemic. I advise people to find some relevant Chromium issue and share their user stories, if they want this to be implemented -- such a high hanging fruit, in light of issues present at any given time in Chrome, won't be picked before after the roof collapses, so to speak.

Answer (score 14):

You can have a look at [Muaz Khan's Library](https://github.com/muaz-khan/MultiStreamsMixer) for multi stream mixing. Or you can go about it something like this:

```js
const screenStream;
const micStream;
const remoteStream;
// merge audio from remote stream and micStream

const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
const source1 = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(micStream);
const source2 = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(remoteStream);
const destination = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();

//connect sources to destination 
// you can add gain nodes if you want 
source1.connect(destination);
source2.connect(destination);

const outputStream= new MediaStream();
outputStream.addTrack(screenStream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
outputStream.addTrack(destination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning the linked implementation only allows mixing audio tracks. So recording multiple video tracks with a single media recorder is currently not solved broadly.

Comment: To mix video tracks you need to render them on a canvas first (arrange them side by side or any way you want) and then capture the stream from canvas @ArmenMichaeli

Comment: I had some weird issues with Chrome if any of this was executed without an User interaction with the website first. No warning or error. Just the sound was not recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution for multiple audio stream in mediaRecord for [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org) call, which I found :

```js
const startRecording = async () => {
    try {
        const screenStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
            video: true,
            audio: true,
        });

        const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
        const source1 = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream.current.srcObject);
        const source2 = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(participantStream.current.srcObject);
        const destination = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
        source1.connect(destination);
        source2.connect(destination);

        const outputStream = new MediaStream();
        outputStream.addTrack(screenStream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
        outputStream.addTrack(destination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
        mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(outputStream);
        mediaRecorderRef.current.ondataavailable = (event) => {
            if (event.data.size > 0) {
                recordedChunksRef.current.push(event.data);
            }
        };
        mediaRecorderRef.current.onstop = () => {
            console.log("dddd");
            setActiveOption({ index: -1 });

            const recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunksRef.current, {
                type: "video/mp4",
            });

            const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
            downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
            downloadLink.download = "recorded-screen.mp4";
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
            document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);

            setRecording(false);
        };

        recordedChunksRef.current = [];
        mediaRecorderRef.current.start();

        screenStream.getVideoTracks()[0].addEventListener("ended", () => {
            setIsOpenRecordingModal(true);
        });

        setRecording(true);
    } catch (error) {
        setActiveOption({ index: -1 });
        console.error("Error accessing screen:", error);
    }
};
```